# Codemod for Babel `import` into commonjs `require`

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, babeljs, require

I'm looking for a way to converting a full node-project's Babel`import`s into CommonJS-style `require()`. The goal is to get rid of Babel.

Considering node.js has things like async/await built-in nowadays it feels redundant to run Babel. The only thing left that Babel does currently is that it converts the ES6-style `import`s into `require()`.

I've been searching but can't find any elegant solution to do it semi-automatically. The output when compiling Babel isn't clean enough to just copy without a lot of manual work.

**If I have a file with input like this:**

```
import express from 'express'
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import authMiddleware from './middlewares/auth'
import { get } from 'lodash'

export const myVar = 1
export default function doSomething() {
  // ...
}
```

**.. I'd want an output similar to this**

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const authMiddleware = require('./middlewares/auth').default
const { get } = require('lodash')

export.myVar = 1
export.default = function doSomething() {
  // ...
}
```

Alternatively that it converted the files to the `.mjs`-syntax for the relative ones and used `require()` for external stuff.

It's not the first time I have an old node project running Babel where it's turned more-and-more redundant with time, so I'm sure someone has done neat solution to this before.

Comment: So you want only the `import/export` syntax transformed, but keep all other code untouched, as-is. Do I get it right?

Comment: Ideally, yes, but I don't mind minor formatting changes as I have a `eslint --fix` precommit hook anyway

Answer (score 3):

I dig up the source code of [`babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`](https://github.com/babel/babel/blob/8c7d4b55c99ff34cb9d493d452472e59b5ed1e70/packages/babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs/src/index.js). Looks like it's impossible to config babel to output your desired result.

Reason behind is the necessity of helpers like `_interopRequireDefault` still holds strong, because ES module is not backward-compat to commonjs, notably the `export default` thing.

Take for example:

```js
// input
import bodyParser from 'body-parser'
import authMiddleware from './middlewares/auth'

// your desired output
const bodyParser = require('body-parser') // <-- no default
const authMiddleware = require('./middlewares/auth').default // <-- default

// actual babel output
var _bodyParser = _interopRequireDefault(require("body-parser"));
var _auth = _interopRequireDefault(require("./middlewares/auth"));
```

You have no way to tell when to add `.default` and when not to. Only proper way to handle this is by wrapping `require()` with `_interopRequireDefault` and do runtime check.

If compiler does trace the required module and check if it's a ES module or commonjs module, then it can tell if `.default` is needed. However babel is designed around a single-file-at-a-time model, so no chance it can do that for you.

I think if you can figure out a reliable rule to tell when to add a `.default` and when not to then perhaps a simple regex-replace will solve your problem.

---

Side note. I do have some idea to hack it out with a customized babel plugin.

You can fork the `babel-plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` source, remove the `_interopRequireDefault` wrapping logic, then you use a resolver to do the aforementioned check-if-requiree-is-esmodule job, then see if `.default` is needed in output.

But easier said than done, this requires some serious effort.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. 

I am aware of it the reason why they have the `_interopRequireDefault`. However, in my case I basically want to just remap all relative paths to `require().default` and all third parties to `require()`. Maybe some of them will be ESModulified already but I can probably do those manually with a regex if they cause issues.

Comment: And yes, I was actually digging on that end the other day but I had to learn so much about Babel that it seems easier to do it manually.

Answer (score 3):

The simple solution, open your source code in an editor that can go through all files I use VSCode and set a ignore on the node_modules folder and do I regex replace on all files the full way if you need the multiple exports is below.

**RegEx way**

Search for:

```
import[\s*]([a-zA-Z0-9,]*)[\s*]from[\s*]['|"]([a-zA-Z0-9\{\},\.\/\\]*)['|"][\s*]
```

replace with

```
const $1 = require('$2')
```

if you use `as` do this also.
Search for:

```
import[\s*][a-zA-Z0-9,]*[\s*]as[\s*]([a-zA-Z0-9]*)[\s*]from[\s*]['|"]([a-zA-Z0-9\{\},\.\/\\]*)['|"][\s*]
```

replace with

```
const $1 = require('$2')
```

there are some drawbacks here you can't use multiple exports for that you need The full way

**Long way**

Ok so for anyone who is interested, here is the process I used to work this out, you can then copy your source out of the build folder into a new location as a new source or overwrite your old src and the remove all of babel from your project (`npm prune`).

This will leave all the support stuff that module needs including the support for export default `_interopRequireDefault()` the only way to get rid of this is to create your own plugin that does not do this.

**Step 1**

Identify what ECMA babel was using for that. So I went to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

it shows that import has been part of the spec since ES6 (also known as ECMA2015)

**Step 2**

The presets are just groups of packages so identify the package for that particular transpile.

Opened my package.json and looked for `babel-preset-es2015` found it. went to node_moduels\babel-preset-es2015, opened it's package.json to find

```
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd": "^6.24.1",
```

**Step 3**

Some testing so using `--plugins=` argument for babel I tested what each of them did on a small set of 2 files one requiring the other to and test each one I worked out it was the commonjs version that was needed for `require();`

**Step 4**

Do the conversion

So make sure you have the following node modules installed `babel-cli, babel-core, babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs`

Then fire up the CLI and do,

```
babel --plugins=transform-es2015-modules-commonjs ./src/ --out-dir build/
```

taken from https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli

Comment: Very good guide! A note on step 3, https://babeljs.io/repl has a feature named "time travel", which does the breaking down "which plugin does which part of the job" for you in an amazing way. Worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `plugin` of [putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) called [@putout/plugin-convert-esm-to-commonjs](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout/tree/master/packages/plugin-convert-esm-to-commonjs) for this purpose. It converts:

```js
import {readFile} from 'fs/promises';
```

To:

```js
const readFile = require('fs/promises');
```

To get things done set up the base line with:

```sh
npx putout . --disable-all
```

Enable `convert-esm-to-commonjs` in configuration file `.putout.json`:

```json
{
    "rules": {
        "convert-esm-to-commonjs": "on"
    }
}
```

And apply fixes:

```sh
npx putout . --fix
```